# How to get files with a particular extension within a folder in python?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm working on a python code. When I change few parameters of run code every time it generates a new folder (containing files with npy extension) within main folder. I want to get access to all npy files in new folder. If I use

```
`os.path.listdir()`
```

it only lists the files in main folder.How I can approach files with npy extension?

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the path of the directory in your function

when you call:

```
`os.path.listdir()`
```

it is going to the current directory by default. If for example your new folder was called foobar then you would need to write it as something like:

```
path = "/foobar/"
os.listdir( path )
```

or equivelantly this *should* work also

```
os.listdir( "/foobar/" )
```

Let me know if you need any clarification

**EDIT**

If you want only files with the npy extension you can use the following code:

```
for file in os.listdir("/foobar"):
if file.endswith(".npy"):
    print(os.path.join("/npy", file))
```

Again, let me know if you need clarification here.

Comment: `os.path.listdir()` uses the current directory, not the root directory.

Comment: @eryksun I have edited my answer accordingly. The point I was attempting to make is that listdir is only showing files in the main folder not the subfolder because he either needs to loop through all child folders or update his `listdir()` to show the folder name that he is wanting to search through

Comment: @William Cross There are some other folders inside foobar folder . Whenever I run my code a new_folder(containing npy files) is created inside Foobar folder. I just want to give a command in such a way that i  every time I access to the that new_folder containing npy files.

Comment: @sara if you know the name of the new folder (even if you can retrieve it dynamically as a variable) you should be able to parse that folder name into the path for `listdir()`. If you don't you would need to modify your listdir function to loop through all subdirectories, but then you would get a list of files from all subfolders not just the newly created one.

Comment: It's not helping if you say `listdir()` defaults to a "main" folder. It defaults to the current directory. This has nothing to do with a "main" folder unless the script has manually called `os.chdir` to change the current directory to a particular folder.

Comment: If you want easier access to file globbing, use the standard library's `glob` module, e.g. `glob.glob('/foobar/*.npy')`.

Comment: As i mentioned that foo bar folder contains some other folders and most of them have npy files. I don't want to access all npy files in different folders. I want to get access to those npy files that are produced a a result of running code. Can you please explain how i can get access to thethat  newfolder?

Comment: you could use the following one-liner to find the most recently created folder and then run the `listdir()` on that: `max(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*/')), key=os.path.getmtime)`. Ultimately if you want to list all npy files within a particular folder, you will need to know the path of that folder relative to the current one in order to run a listdir function on it. If that makes sense?

Comment: In my code I'm using os.mkdir(new_folder name). Can i store it as a variable?

Comment: I don't have globe module in my system. I want to use some other command. If possible can you please suggest some other command

Comment: if you're dynamically setting that folder name, then store it as a variable before you run mkdir. For example first you would set `$newfolder = new_folder_name` and then run `os.mkdir($newfolder)`. This is assuming that the folder names are being created based on variables (like timestamps). If you have it stored in that variable you can then reference it later inside your listdir() function

Comment: One more thing that I want to mention is that I am changing folder name from command line

Comment: if you change folder into the newly created folder, then your listdir function should work without specifying a path.